# Open camera view upon app Startup (iOS6)

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

what im trying to do is to have the app open up with the camera as the first screen. It isn't working and i don't know what im missing. If anyone can fill me in that would be wonderful... Thanks.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
else
{
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}


}
```

Comment: perform this in `viewWillAppear`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that. Hope it helps you:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```