# UIImagePickerController chashes in ios6

Tags: iphone, button, uiimagepickercontroller

my app crashes when i touch my take photo button, in ios 6 and i really dont understand how to fix it... (im a n00b) :)

take a look in my code, Buttons.h :

```
 @interface Buttons : UIViewController
    <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate>

    @property BOOL newMedia;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    - (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender;
    @end

Buttons.m :

#import "Buttons.h"




 @implementation Buttons

    - (void) useCamera:(id)sender
    {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                               animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
    }
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {


        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];




    }

    -(void)image:(UIImage *)image
    finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
     contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
    {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                                  message: @"Failed to save image"
                                  delegate: nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    @end

    @implementation UIImagePickerController (NonRotating)

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        return NO;
    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    @end
```

sorry if im too n00b to handle :)
if anyone could read through my code, and fix my little problem...
i would be the happiest man in the world...

matthijs

edit : i dont know if i found the error but this came up :

2013-02-22 16:35:09.886 Harold[81732:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e1a012 0x13bae7e 0x754f31 0x746b99 0x746c14 0x13ce705 0x3022c0 0x302258 0x3c3021 0x3c357f 0x3c26e8 0x331cef 0x331f02 0x30fd4a 0x301698 0x2053df9 0x2053ad0 0x1d8fbf5 0x1d8f962 0x1dc0bb6 0x1dbff44 0x1dbfe1b 0x20527e3 0x2052668 0x2feffc 0x2c3d 0x2b65)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];`?

Comment: @Ares my app just closes when im pressing the take a picture button, but maybe it happends because, i have 2 viewcontrollers on my storyboard... i dont know...

Comment: @Rajesh where should i put that ? sorry :)

Comment: At the place where you have specified `imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];`

Comment: @Rajesh tried it, but unfortunately it does not work...

Comment: Please try debugging to see where it is crashing. NSLog can also help.

Comment: Try [self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES]; There will be a warning about this method being deprecated, but do me a favor and ignore that for the time being. Also, is there a segue connected with your Button?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below on your button action & check:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

imagePicker.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: See my this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576357/open-camera-view-upon-app-startup-ios6/13577245#13577245